# Django rest create different objects with serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

In my project I have created a custom User object with a one to one relation to a Profile object in order to isolate authentication fields.

Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/user_images/default.png', upload_to='user_images', blank=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
       return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
        profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, related_name="user" ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
        is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' 
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

        objects = CustomUserManager()

        def __str__(self):
           return self.email
```

My problem now is that i want to create the Profile object with the same request of the User object

View

```
class CustomView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Serializer
class CustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

```
# User
email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)    
password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)

# Profile
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
image = serializers.ImageField(allow_null=True, max_length=100, required=False)

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile = Profile.objects.create(
        first_name = validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name = validated_data['first_name'],
        image = validated_data['image'],
    )
    user = User.objects.create(
        email = validated_data['email'],
        profile = profile
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user
```

Now in the database everything is created correctly but i receive this error

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field
> `first_name` on serializer `CustomSerializer`. The serializer field
> might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `User` instance. Original exception text was: 'User' object has no
> attribute 'first_name'.

I suppose this means that a serializer can only handle the creation of one model so i'm supposed to handle my case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your error comes from `to_representation()` and what you can do is to set `write_only=True` on first_name, last_name and image fields like this:

```
first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, write_only=True)
```

However, a more clean solution would be to use `ModelSerialzier` for both `User` and `Profile` models. If you do so, you'll have something like:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "image")

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("id", "email", "profile", [...])
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
```